# Replace row on a condition from one dataframe to another with different lengths [python]

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two dataframes df1 and df2 with same columns (23 columns - to be exact), but different lengths. There are some rows in df1 with the same ID as in df2. what I want to do is to check where the same IDs are 
-> If in df1 for columns 'A' or 'C' **is empty** , but at the same ID in df2 column 'A' or 'C' **is NOT empty** ,replace df1 row with df2.

I can't use **combine_first**, because I have some rows with same IDs but the column 'D' is different . 
Because of this column 'D' I can't just use **fillna** ,because this column also needs to be updated.- and this columns is never empty.

I will try to explain my problem with an example :

```
print(DF1['ID','A','B','C','D'].head()):

     ID            A         B              C          D
0   70_400.1      NaN  7027514279         NaN     11-08  15:35
1   70_400.2      NaN  7027514279         NaN     11-08  15:35
2   70_500.1  95011.0  7027514279    5.000000     11-08  15:35
3   70_500.2  95011.0  7027514279    5.000000     11-08  15:35
4   70_500.3      NaN  7027514279         NaN     11-08  15:35
```

```
print(DF2['ID','A','B','C','D'].head()):
     ID            A         B              C          D
0   70_400.1  95011.2  7027514279         NaN     19-08  15:45
1   70_400.2  95011.2  7027514279    5.000000     19-08  14:30
2   70_500.1  95011.0  7027514279    5.000000     15-08  12:39
3   70_500.2  95011.0  7027514279    5.000000     14-08  19:27
4   70_500.3      NaN  7027514279         NaN     12-08  11:49
```

my desired output for DF1 should be like :

```
     ID            A         B              C          D
0   70_400.1  95011.2  7027514279         NaN     19-08  15:45
1   70_400.2  95011.2  7027514279    5.000000     19-08  14:30
2   70_500.1  95011.0  7027514279    5.000000     11-08  15:35
3   70_500.2  95011.0  7027514279    5.000000     11-08  15:35
4   70_500.3      NaN  7027514279         NaN     11-08  15:35
```

I tried this , but it means I can update only one value in a row , and there is no option for me to also change the column 'D' since it can be different even if the update hasn't occured. And also this means that for one row to be filled it has to go through the file multiple times, which is not efficient way to do this.

```
df1.loc[(numpy.isnan(df1.A)),'A'] = df1['ID'].map(df2.set_index('ID')['A'])
```

I tried and searched for the solution but nothing I found on stackoverflow wasn't the right answer for me.

Some of the questions I looked were :

[[Replace rows in a Pandas df with rows from another df of different size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52015221/replace-rows-in-a-pandas-df-with-rows-from-another-df-of-different-size][blog])

[[adding row from one dataframe to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57504557/adding-row-from-one-dataframe-to-another][blog])

[[Python/Pandas - Replacing an element in one dataframe with a value from another dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38371181/python-pandas-replacing-an-element-in-one-dataframe-with-a-value-from-another][blog])

Hope someone has an answer since. I am still pretty new to this whole python/pandas coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First separate the rows you can't change on column D using `merge` and `loc` then apply `combine_first`

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on = 'ID')
df4 = df3.loc[((df3['A_x']).isna() & (df3['A_y'].isna()))
          &   ((df3['C_x']).isna() & (df3['C_y'].isna()))]

dftemp = df1.copy()

#Create a bool array where he can't change column D
mask = ~df1.ID.isin(df4.ID)


dftemp.loc[
    (mask) 
    & ((dftemp['A'].isna()) | (dftemp['C'].isna())), 'D'] = np.nan

dftemp = dftemp.set_index('ID')
df2 = df2.set_index('ID')


dftemp = dftemp.combine_first(df2[['A', 'C', 'D']])

dftemp.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

output:

```
    ID         A        B           C   D   
0   70_400.1    95011.2 7027514279  NaN 19-08 15:35
1   70_400.2    95011.2 7027514279  5.0 19-08 15:35
2   70_500.1    95011.0 7027514279  5.0 11-08 15:35
3   70_500.2    95011.0 7027514279  5.0 11-08 15:35
4   70_500.3    NaN     7027514279  NaN 11-08 15:35
```

Comment: I just runed the code, at first it was giving me some emty 'D' rows, but I figured out what was the problem. At the merge you just specified that it takes IDs that are in both df1 and df2 and forget about the rest. I just added in the first row `df3 = df1.merge(df2, on = 'ID', how='outer')`  and it worked perfectly :D thank you for your help

Comment: just a quick question while you are online, I just noticed that the rows that only exist in df2 are copied too - which is great, but they only get the values from columns 'A' , 'C' and 'D' the rest are empty :/ how can I change that ?

Comment: if you need a copy without empty values you can remove the columns selected on df2 on combine_first like this `combine_first(df2)`. I believe this will fix your problem

Comment: in 2021, may i ask whats is the purpose of 
#Create a bool array where he can't change column D
mask = ~df1.ID.isin(df4.ID)


dftemp.loc[
    (mask) 
    & ((dftemp['A'].isna()) | (dftemp['C'].isna())), 'D'] = np.nan


I have try adding this or without adding this will get  the SAME result